# How can I find out how a commit landed in a Git branch?

Tags: git

A feature that was supposed to be in a side branch, suddenly appeared in our production branch in Git. What I *expect* to have happened, is that someone pushed the wrong local branch to the remote production branch, with the local branch ahead of the remote production branch.

However, there isn't really a way to tell whether this happened, as the merge on the remote would've been a fast-forward merge. Is there another way to find out how this happened?

Comment: what does `git log` tell you?

Comment: Might be helpful to describe your workflow. Stable branch is usually master

Comment: We have four branches for dev, test, acceptance and production, and code usually flows through those branches in that order. Before landing in dev, code lives in feature branches. `git log` in the production branch lists the erroneous commits, the merge commit merging the unstable code from the feature branch to the dev branch, and a merge commit from the acceptance branch to the production branch that does not include the unstable code.

Answer (score 0):

You can display the full log with the history or to use any GUI.

git has a build in tool named `gitk`
You can also simply run `git log` form the command lien to view the full tree

`git log --oneline --decorate --graph`

The above command out put example:
[image: Git log Output example]

Answer (score -1):

We did find the erroneous merge - apparently it wasn't a fast-forward merge, but a regular one with an altered commit message. The reason we missed it in the first place, was that a merge commit has *two* diffs: one for each original branch, comparing it to the result of the merge. Unfortunately, we only saw one of diffs, which did not include the unstable code. After finding this out, we rechecked the merge commits that took place after the commits that shouldn't have been there, and checked the other diffs. We then found the incriminating merge commit.

Comment: I'll leave the question open in case some one answers with a way to find out when fast-forward merges have taken place.

Comment: Please don't provide updates to the question as a separate answer; instead, provide updates on the question itself. This answer doesn't tell anyone any way of finding out how to solve the problem.

Comment: That's why I didn't accept it, however: it did explain how _I_ came to find out how the commit landed in that branch. It includes possibly helpful information (i.e. merge commits have multiple diffs), and provides the answer to _my_ specific question. If there's a more generic answer for future searchers, that'd be nice, but my answer is relevant to a subset of them as well.